# methods inherited from Object are rendered ambiguous

Tags: scala

```
val x: AnyRef = 42
```

> type mismatch: found `Int(42)` required: `AnyRef`
>
> Note: an implicit exists from `scala.Int => java.lang.Integer`, but **methods inherited from `Object` are rendered ambiguous**. This is to avoid a blanket implicit which would convert any `scala.Int` to any `AnyRef`.
>
> You may wish to use a type ascription: `x: java.lang.Integer`

I don't understand the emphasized part. What methods are rendered ambiguous, and how come? Are methods inherited from Object always "rendered ambiguous" in Scala? Is this a special scenario where methods somehow wind up multiple times in a type? I just don't see where the ambiguity comes from.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Scala has to pretend that `Int` is in a different place in the inheritance hierarchy than Java places it.  This results in some awkwardness.

Consider the method `notify`.  Waiting on an `Int` doesn't work--it's a primitive.  Waiting on a newly-boxed `java.lang.Integer` doesn't work either, since the other threads may have ended up with their own separately-boxed `Integer`s.  You just don't want `notify` to work on an `Int`--it's the wrong thing to do.

But if you have the conversion `Int => java.lang.Integer` without anything unusual, you *will* be able to call `notify` on your `Int`.

To prevent this sort of usually-wrong behavior, the mechanism for failing to resolve a conversion due to ambiguity is hijacked.  This keeps `Int => java.lang.Integer` serving to convert `Int` where `AnyRef` is expected (which would break the inheritance hierarchy), and prevents things like `42.notifyAll` from working since even though `java.lang.Integer` has that method, the inferencing machinery is kept from noticing it.

The message you see is supposed to cover both the `42.notify` case than the `42: AnyRef` case.

Comment: Can you expand on "the mechanism for failing to resolve a conversion due to ambiguity is hijacked"? This is exactly what I don't understand.